# Как поменять директорию установки пакетов в winget

Tags: windows

Возникла проблема с тем, что winget ставит пакеты в C:\Program Files, а хочется поменять эту директорию на другую)

Comment: Кто-то доупстил ошибку на этапе проектирования и сделал маленький диск C:\?

Comment: Да, к сожалению, так и произошло :(

Comment: Тогда не городи костыли и просто сделай изначально всё хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не первый:

https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/201

https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/337

https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/489

Судя по статусу `open` - *пока что* - нет.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо за ответ :)))